# Trying to get midi2vjoy to work, pygame.midi.Input causes a segmentation fault

Tags: python, pygame, midi

miditest.py

```
import sys, os, time, traceback
import ctypes
import pygame.midi
import winreg

pygame.midi.init()
try:
    print(pygame.midi.get_device_info(1))
    m = pygame.midi.Input(1)
    print('Device opened for testing. Use ctrl-c to quit.')
    while True:
        while m.poll():
            print(m.read(1))
        time.sleep(0.1)
except:
    m.close()
pygame.midi.quit()
```

This is part of the code of [midi2vjoy](https://github.com/c0redumb/midi2vjoy/), it is used to test midi input for later configuration. the line

```
m = pygame.midi.Input(1)
```

causes the output

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
(b'MMSystem', b'DDJ-200', 1, 0, 0)
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00003b98 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\midi.py", line 280 in __init__
  File "miditest.py", line 9 in <module>
```

as you can see before the error a midi device exists at that device index and it is an input device.
The line 280 in midi.py is

```
self._input = _pypm.Input(device_id, buffer_size)
```

Comment: I noticed you are using python 3.8 and pygame 1.9.6. Upgrade to pygame 2.0.0.dev6 with `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`. Maybe it has nothing to do with this particular error but I think it's worth trying because I also had some errors with this combo of versions, and updating to this pygame version resolved it.

Comment: @kaktus_car That actually solved the issue thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it did! You're welcome.

Comment: @kaktuz_car you should add it as answer below :), solved it for me too!